# HTML5 валидация перед JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Как можно запустить валидацию формы с помощью HTML5 перед исполнением скрипта?

html

```
<form action="#">
  <input id="a" type="number" max="10" required>
  +
  <input id="b" type="number" max="10" required>
  =
  <input id="c" type="number" />
  <button id='sub' type="submit">Посчитать</button>
</form>
```

js

```
function calc () {
  var a = $('#a').val();
  var b = $('#b').val();
  var c = a + b;
  $('#c').val(c);
}
console.log($('#a').val());
$('#sub').click(function(){
  console.log('click')
  calc();
})
```

Сейчас, если нажать на кнопку *Посчитать*, то сначала будет выведен результат, а потом появится сообщение о невалидном значении.

Необходимо, чтобы когда я ввожу числа и нажимаю *Посчитать*, сначала происходила стандартная валидация, а потом происходило исполнение скрипта.

P.S.: в оригинальном скрипте я использую JQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можете использовать вместо события `click` у кнопки, событие `submit` у формы

```js
function calc() {
  var a = $('#a').val();
  var b = $('#b').val();
  var c = a + b;
  $('#c').val(c);
}
console.log($('#a').val());

$('#f').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit');
  calc();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="f">
  <input id="a" type="number" max="10" required>+
  <input id="b" type="number" max="10" required>=
  <input id="c" type="number" />
  <button id='sub' type="submit">Посчитать</button>
</form>
```

Comment: не успел на 10 секунд...)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, :-D бывает :-) так-то ответ давно готов был, просто пока то, се, не писалось :) думал кто-то опередит :)

Comment: То что нужно! Спасибо! Добавлю, что если требуется что бы action не происходил (страница не обновлялась) можно добавить в action такой код action="javascript:0"

Comment: @dbellkoff, эм, нет, достаточно сделать `e.preventDefault();` как сделано у меня в коде. В этом вы можете убедиться запустив сниппет: обновления нет, и `action="javascript:0"` в разметке тоже нет

Answer (score 2):

1. Добавьте форме `id`: `<form id="myForm" action="#">`
2. В JavaScript-коде проверяйте `.checkValidity()` формы и используйте `event.preventDefault()`, чтобы предотвратить постинг формы на сервер.
3. Не забывайте про `parseInt()`, иначе будете складывать строки, а не числа :)

```js
function calc() {
  var a = parseInt($('#a').val());
  var b = parseInt($('#b').val());
  var c = a + b;
  $('#c').val(c);
}

$('#sub').click(function(event) {
  if ($('#myForm')[0].checkValidity()) {
    calc();
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $('#c').val('');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="#">
  <input id="a" type="number" max="10" required>+
  <input id="b" type="number" max="10" required>=
  <input id="c" type="number" />
  <button id='sub' type="submit">Посчитать</button>
</form>
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/jgyn2gwv/**

Comment: @Grundy это очень грубо — без спросу менять чужой ответ, в особенности когда изменения уже один раз были откачены.

Comment: Если есть возможность вставить сниппет напрямую не используя сторонние сайты - лучше воспользоваться этой возможностью

Comment: Изменения повышающие качество ответа всегда приветствуются, а ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, когда без них можно обойтись - нет

Comment: В ответе уже присутствует весь необходимый код. Пожалуйста, больше не изменяйте мой ответ.

Comment: а так же ознакомьтесь с темой на мете: [Правка чужих ответов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2277/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/2279#2279)

Comment: @Alex, если есть возможность не использовать сторонние ресурсы - лучше ей воспользоваться.

Comment: @Alex, скорее здесь не дубляж кода, а конкретно пример, поэтому сниппет и скрыт по умолчанию

Comment: Код мало того, что продублирован, так ещё и плохо отформатирован. Это только собьёт читателя с толку.

Comment: @ДмитрийШевченко, выровнил форматирование

Comment: @Alex спасибо! Так гораздо лучше!

Comment: Предоставлять код примеров ссылками в jsfiddle действительно не стоит - у нас есть свой встроенный редактор (snippet). Чтобы редактировать сниппет целиком, в режиме редактирования в области предпросмотра есть кнопка. По ней можно открыть код в редакторе сниппета. Конечно, можно и напрямую править.

Comment: Похоже, Grundy не заметил, что тот же самый код уже есть выше, потому и разместил его ещё раз.